# Get AS3 instance method reference from Class object

Tags: actionscript-3, function, reflection, function-pointers

```
class Foo {
   public function bar():void { ... }
}

var clazz:Class = Foo;

// ...enter the function (no Foo literal here)
var fun:Function = clazz["bar"]; // PROBLEM: returns null

// later
fun.call(new Foo(), ...);
```

What is the correct way to do the above? The Java equivalent of what I want to do is:

```
Method m = Foo.class.getMethod("bar", ...);
m.invoke(new Foo(), ...);
```

---

Actual code (with workaround):

```
class SerClass {

    public var className:String;
    public var name:String;
    private var ser:String = null;
    private var unser:Function = null;

    public function SerClass(clazz:Class):void {

        var type:XML = describeType(clazz);

        className = type.@name;

        // determine name
        name = type.factory.metadata.(@name=="CompactType").arg.(@key=="name").@value;

        // find unserializer
        var mdesc:XML = XML(type.method.metadata.(@name=="Unserialize")).parent();
        if (mdesc is XML) {
            unser = clazz[mdesc.@name];
        }

        // find serializer
        var sdesc:XML = XML(type.factory.method.metadata.(@name=="Serialize")).parent();
        if (sdesc is XML) {
            ser = sdesc.@name;
        }


    }
    public function serialize(obj:Object, ous:ByteArray):void {
        if (ser == null) throw new Error(name + " is not serializable");
        obj[ser](ous);
    }
    public function unserialize(ins:ByteArray):Object {
        if (unser == null) throw new Error(name + " is not unserializable");
        return unser.call(null, ins);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you do var fun : Function = Foo["bar"]?

Comment: The same, I expect. I can't do that anyway. `clazz` is a parameter to a function.

Comment: As said before method bar is not accessible before Foo is instanciated. Maybe you should post what you are really trying todo ?

Comment: @Patrick: I want to get a reference to an instance method of a class, then later invoke it on a random (externally created) instance of that class.

Comment: @Bart I'm looking for this too. Found an answer already? I've tried the prototype property, but unfortunately it doesn't work as in JS.
I can't believe however that this isn't possible. W/o using a string for the method name that is.

Comment: @Creynders I haven't looked further, because the workaround works fine for me. I'd still be happy to find a proper solution though.

Comment: @Bart It's just not possible. I asked 2 of the most brilliant AS dev on this planet, and they confirmed: https://gist.github.com/1a6da0c8b1d5322940fe

Comment: @Creynders Ok, good to have closure on that one (pun intended)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My workaround is to store the function name instead of the `Function` object.

```
var fun:String = "bar";

// later...
new Foo()[fun](...);
```

Comment: that is what i said yesterday you have to instanciate the class to be able to call the method ;)

Comment: @Patrick: I am calling the method on an instance, as I've explained in the question and some comments. Thanks for trying to help, but I think you just don't understand what I need to do and I can't explain further.

Comment: Accepting this workaround for now. It looks like it's not possible otherwise, or nobody knows how. I'll happily accept the right answer if it's ever posted.

Comment: As everyone stated in their answers you have to instantiate the object unless it is static. This is not a work around this is how it is.

Comment: @The_asMan: As I've commented on most answers and comments, I have an instance when I'm calling the method. That's the `new Foo()` above. I just don't have it when finding out what the right method is.

Comment: This shouldn't work either you are not type casting the new instance. you need to do something like (new Foo() as Foo)["bar"](...).

Comment: @The_asMan: Casting `new Foo()` as `Foo`? That's the most unnecessary cast I might have ever seen ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here the function bar only exist when your class is instanciated :

```
var foo:Foo = new Foo()
var fun:Function = foo.bar // <-- here you can get the function from the new instance
```

if you want to access it directlty you have to make it static:

```
class Foo {
 public static function bar():void{ ... }
}
```

now you can access your function from the class Foo:

```
var fun:Function = Foo.bar
```

or

```
var clazz:Class = Foo
var fun:Function = clazz["bar"]
```

Comment: I don't have, and cannot create, an instance of `Foo` when reading its `bar` function. bar is also correctly not static. In the last line I'm calling it with a `Foo` instance as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are intending to do.

However [AS3Commons](http://www.as3commons.org/), especially the reflect package have API's that let you work with methods, instances and properties of a class.

There are also API methods to create instances of certain class types on the fly and call their respective methods.

Cheers

Comment: I want to get a reference to an instance method of a class, then later invoke it on a random (externally created) instance of that class.

Comment: In all the discussion in the other comments, I almost forgot this answer. I'll take a look that library. Looks like it can make my working code nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not

```
 fun.call(new Foo(), ...);
```

Use instead since no parameters are required for the function

```
fun.call(clazz);
```

The first parameter as specified by adobe docs.
An object that specifies the value of thisObject within the function body.

[EDIT]
Forgot to point out you have to instantiate a non-static class with the "new" keyword.

```
var clazz:Class = new Foo();
```

[EDIT2]
Ok I played around and think I got what you want.

base.as

```
package{
  public class Base {
    public function Base() {
      trace('Base constructor')
    }
    public function someFunc( ){
      trace('worked');
    }
  }
}



//called with 
var b:Base = new Base( );// note I am not type casting to Class
var func:Function = b.someFunc;
func.call( );
```

Comment: The function is not static, so `this` should be an instance, not the class.

Comment: var clazz:Class = Foo; is an instance. The first parameter is the instance you want to run the function on. In your question you asked what is the correct way to do this, and I posted it for you. You mentioned nothing about static. Do you want it static? If so then declare the method as static.

Comment: In another comment you said-"I want to get a reference to an instance method of a class, then later invoke it on a random (externally created) instance of that class." then this is how you do it.

Comment: clazz, in your comment, is not an instance of Foo but an instance of Class (which describes the class Foo)

Comment: Ahh not sure how I missed that. What you are trying to do is not OOP standard practice. To call a method of a non-static object you need to know the object. What you want is like having a click function for a button but not knowing what button it belongs to. The only way I know of to do what you want is to make the class static so there will only be one instance of the class. You should be storing a reference to the class object anyway, not the function. You might want to rethink your design pattern for this project.

Comment: I know all about OOP, thank's very much :P I want to call a known method on a known instance of a class. I just want to find out about that method before the instance is known.

Comment: Ok, lets try another approach. What exactly do you need/do with the method where you can't wait until you have the instance of the object?

Comment: I edited my code and got it working, but it will default to calling the method with the instance of the object when it was created.

Comment: No, that's not it. I can't create an instance of the class when acquiring the reference to the method.